# Insert page breaks in Excel to split data for printing .pdf

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, printing

I am working with an Excel file that can contains dynamic rows. I export it to .pdf and it works well. The matter is that all the content is on a single page in the .pdf file.

Is there anyway to insert page breaks in my VBA for my .pdf file?

**EDIT:** Here is my code for the page break. Won't seems to get working

```
If count > 30 Then ' count is the number of row. Break at every 15 rows
        Set ws = Range("A1", "K" & count) 'The range of the document
        Dim ii As Integer
        ii = 21 ' first page break
        While count > 0
            If count > 15 Then ' no page break if there is less than 15 rows
             ws.Rows(ii).EntireRow.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
            End If               
            ii = ii + 15
            count = count - 15
        Wend
End If
```

**EDIT 2:** I did not find any way to create a page break into the pdf file. However, I still resolve my problem. I just find a module for vba to run external process and wait for them. it is [ShellAndWait](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ShellAndWait.aspx)

I save every page of my pdf file as a temporary document and send it's path/name to a  C# console application that I've created. I am using the library [PDFsharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFsharp/) to process the pdf documents and then merge them to 1 file.

Hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 4):

You can setup the page breaks like this :

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(25)
Worksheets("Sheet1").VPageBreaks.Add Before:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("J")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(25).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("J").PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
```

*FYI, I didn't managed to make the `Range.PageBreak` to work*

Or for a range, something like this :

```
With Range(blabla)
    .Rows(.Rows.Count).EntireRow.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    '.Rows(Int(.Rows.Count/2)).EntireRow.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    .Columns(.Columns.Count).EntireColumn.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
End With
```

---

**Here is your corrected code :**

```
Sub test_Wanceslas()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    Rg As Range, _
    LastRow As Long, _
    Count As Long, _
    ii As Long

ii = 21 ' first page break
Set Ws = ActiveSheet

With Ws
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Count = LastRow
    Set Rg = .Range("A1", "K" & Count) 'The range of the document

    If LastRow > 30 Then ' count is the number of row. Break at every 15 rows
        .ResetAllPageBreaks
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = Rg.Address

        While Count > 0 And ii < LastRow
            If Count > 15 Then ' no page break if there is less than 15 rows left
                '.Rows(ii).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
                .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.Rows(ii)
            End If
            ii = ii + 15
            Count = Count - 15
        Wend
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: actually, I am exporting a range to pdf since I don't want to export the whole sheet. There is extra button in the sheet that I don't want to see in the pdf file.

It seems that the page break is not working with a range...

Comment: Take a look at the edit, you just need to work around your range! ;)

Comment: Thanks, but it still not working. I've edited my post and added my code, if you can see anything.

Comment: I can't seem to make the `Range.PageBreak` to work, but I corrected your code and included the other ways to set Page Breaks! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the correction of my code. Actually the range is good, but I still get the same probleme. There is no page break in my pdf file. I'm starting to think to make more than 1 pdf file and then to merge them together lol

Comment: What method are you using to get the PDF file? if it is via code, please provide it too! :)

Comment: What do you mean? How I do export to pdf?

Comment: I mean how do you create the PDF file from the Excel file? Do you Print it with something like PDF creator? Save as PDF via Excel? Do it via VBA?

Comment: I just edited my post, I have resolved my problem. Thank for helping :)