# VBA Excel Save to PDF includes blank(hidden) pages.

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a document which contains Yes/No drop downs for sections of the page to be included within the pdf when it's saved.

However once the rows are hidden, when I save as a PDF they are still included as a blank page. Does anyone know a way around this?

[LINK TO GOOGLE DRIVE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1syGrdwCYnrnS77Zq0u72qBXkN_5kP0Aq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel page breaks via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986497/excel-page-breaks-via-vba). Just set the print area and the page breaks (for the area to be printed) accordingly and "print to PDF" will produce the desired (preset) amount of pages as set forth. Maybe this one can be of additional help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673865/insert-page-breaks-in-excel-to-split-data-for-printing-pdf

Comment: I am quite reluctant to open unknown .xlsm file from I don' know who. And other should be too.

Comment: Thanks, for the response Ralph. Unfortunately,with page breaks being sequential, it still picks up the blank pages. I'm trying to only print pages 2, 5 and 8 etc. The page breaks still pick up the other ones.