# Insert page breaks when exporting range in .PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm trying to export a dynamic excel range to .PDF through VBA. 
The thing is, the PDF need to be printable after (letter format), and while it works just fine at the beginning, when too many rows are present (the number of columns is fixed), the whole range shrinks to stay on a single letter page.

I'm trying to set page breaks, but I just cannot make it work. I already tried solutions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673865/insert-page-breaks-in-excel-to-split-data-for-printing-pdf), but it does not seem to work either.

There are other things aside the range I want to export, so exporting the whole sheet is not an option, and it's at work, so third-party dowloaded programs cannot make it either.

Here is my code:

```
Sub saveAsPDF(targetWksht As Worksheet, fileName As String)

    lastRow = getLastRow(targetWksht) 'gets last row of the desired range
    lastCol = getLAstCol(targetWksht) 'gets last column of the desired range (always 8)
    pageBreakIndex = 40

    With targetWksht
        .ResetAllPageBreaks
        While pageBreakIndex < lastRow
            .Rows(pageBreakIndex).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
            pageBreakIndex = pageBreakIndex + 50
        Wend
    End With

    With targetWksht.Range(targetWksht.Cells(1,1), targetWksht.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                             fileName:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName, _
                             Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                             IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                             OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

I always get the same result: my range, properly formatted, but in one block fitted in a landscape-oriented letter sheet, that shrinks as the range expands vertically. Cannot find a way to break pages for it to appear in multiple sheets.

Comment: I have a worksheet that expands and shrinks as rows are added and deleted and in code have the print area set by `Worksheets(TargetTab).PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$" & FR & ":$R$" & LR` where FR and LR are the first and last row. Then, in the ribbon, Page Layout > Width = 1 Page, and Height = Automatic. The "Automatic" is the essential setting that lets multiple pages happen. While my case applies to printing, I think it applies to exporting too.

Comment: @Stax just tried putting Page Layout > Width = 1 Page, and Height = Automatic. Works just fine! Thank you. For some reason though, the second page is offset so I don't have the first two lines that appear, but I'll find a way to fix this. It applies to exporting too!